# Lightning Dynamic Style width setting using aura:attribute value binding

Tags: lightning, dynamic-style

Can anyone please help me here,

```
<aura:attribute name="failureCount" type="Integer" default="2"/>
<aura:attribute name="totalStatusCount" type="Integer" default="2"/>
<div class="status">Failed</div>
  <div class="thermometer"> 
    <p class="downloads failure" style="{! 'width: ' + v.failureCount*100/totalStatusCount + '%'}">
      <span style="margin-right: 10px;">{!v.failureCount}</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to bind the failureCount and totalStatusCount from  to set the width of

but I am getting "width:NaN%" while viewing in Inspect element.

Any help much appreciated, thanks in advance

Regards,
Kiruthika

Comment: When You are setting that value? onInit?

Comment: Can you edit the post and add the code too, to understand this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use the "value provider" for totalStatusCount:

```
<p class="downloads failure" 
    style="{! 'width: ' + v.failureCount*100/v.totalStatusCount + '%'}">
```

As an aside, I would recommend that you consider using a [lightning:progressBar](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_progressBar.htm) as a matter of giving it a similar appearance to other Lightning components.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable answer, It's working now

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, Thank you so much for your valuable suggestion to use lightning:progressBar. I am trying to use it but I am not able to change its standard color which is light blue. Can you please let me know how to change the color of lightning:progressBar. Thanks in advance